# Create a custom function that returns JLabel to main JFrame?

Tags: java, oop, scope, jframe, jlabel

I hope I can remember to include all my details so here it goes.

I'm working with Java and I'm creating my own interface with the main window being a JFrame, the background is attached to the JFrame with a Background image(as JLabel) that fits exactly with the window. Then I have an image that is attached to the background Jlabel to act as a "start" button.  My problem is I'd like to create a custom class that will facilitate each buttons functions inside its own class.

so instead of having functions in the main class that will react to the buttons, I'd like to make a class that can be added to the background... here is my code maybe someone could give me an example and I can figure out the rest or point me in the right direction.

**The following code contains the original, please provide an example of how you would change it to encapulate eventlisteners in its own class for the Jlabel button**

```
    import java.awt.*;

    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;



    public class pipboy{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    pipboy pipboy_os = new pipboy();
    pipboy_os.runmain();
}

public void runmain(){
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PIPBOY Research v0.0.03");

    //background
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("UI/background/default.png");
        JLabel label=new JLabel(background);


    //radiation animated
    ImageIcon animated_loading = new ImageIcon("UI/icon/loading/loading.png");
    JLabel animated_icon = new JLabel(animated_loading);
    animated_icon.setSize(128, 128);
    animated_icon.setLocation(300, 125);

    //Buff arm guy icon
    ImageIcon icon_loading = new ImageIcon("UI/icon/34.png");
    JLabel icon = new JLabel(icon_loading);
    icon.setSize(128, 128);
    icon.setLocation(300, 50);


    label.add(icon);
    label.add(animated_icon);
    frame.add(label);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //Full screen
     frame.setSize(800,480);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

    //Set default close operation for JFrame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    //This is the handler class i made but i want it in its own class with the buff arm icon picure so it can do something specific when the image is pressed
    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    frame.addMouseListener(handler);
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
}

private static class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I didn't know how polymorhpism worked in Java but here is my solution (with some names altered)

```
import javax.swing.*;

class GUItests{
    public JFrame mainContainerFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUItests mainController = new GUItests();
        mainController.startGUI();
    }

    public void startGUI(){
        mainContainerFrame = new JFrame("test Frame");

        mainContainerFrame.setSize(800,480);
        mainContainerFrame.pack();
        mainContainerFrame.setVisible(true);

        mainContainerFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel customButtonVar = customButton();
        mainContainerFrame.getContentPane().add(customButtonVar);

    }


    public JLabel customButton(){
        JLabel icon = new JLabel("testing");
        icon.setSize(128, 128);
        icon.setLocation(300, 50);
        return icon;
    }

}
```